# Writing junction for multiple joins using join-monster-graphql-tools-adapter in graphql and join-monster

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have been trying to write junction and I am using join-monster-graphql-tools-adapter. Here is the sample code

```
assets:{
          junction: {
            sqlTable: 'FPAS',
          sqlJoins: [(contractTable, junctionTabel) => `${contractTable}.CONTRACT_ID =${junctionTabel}.CONTRACT_ID`,
                     (junctionTabel,assetTable) => `${junctionTabel}.ASSET_ID = ${assetTable}.ASSET_ID`]
        }
```

but while testing it fails with error message: **Cannot read property 'sqlTable' of undefined**

Could anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a brief struggle I figured out what was the problem. It was a bracket that was misplaced. Hence I can conclude that **junction in join-monster-graphql-tools-adapter is working**.
Example of the joinMonsterAdapt is below.

```
joinMonsterAdapt(schema, {
  Query: {
    fields: {
      // add a function to generate the "where condition"
      contract: {
        where: (table, args) => `${table}.CODE LIKE '%${args.code}'`
      }
    }
  },
Contract: {
    sqlTable: 'DataLakeCMS.CONTRACT',
    uniqueKey: 'CONTRACT_ID',
    fields: {
      contractId: {
        sqlColumn: 'CONTRACT_ID'
      },
      assets: {
        junction: {
          sqlTable: 'Con_Pas',
          uniqueKey: 'PrimaryKey',
          sqlJoins: [
            // first the parent table to the junction
            (contractTable, junctionTable, args) =>
              `${contractTable}.ID = ${junctionTable}.ID`,
            // then the junction to the child
            (junctionTable, assetTable, args) =>
              `${junctionTable}.ID = ${assetTable}.ID`
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```